Document loading failed on Nextcloud office
I can't open a document in Nextcloud Office
The Basics
Nextcloud Server version (e.g., 29.x.x):
    30.0.2
Operating system and version (e.g., Ubuntu 24.04):
    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Web server and version (e.g, Apache 2.4.25):
    nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Reverse proxy and version _(e.g. nginx 1.27.2)
    nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
PHP version (e.g, 8.3):
    PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.19 (cli) (built: Sep 30 2024 16:25:25) (NTS)
Is this the first time you’ve seen this error? (Yes / No):
    yah
When did this problem seem to first start?
    After installation
Installation method (e.g. AIO, NCP, Bare Metal/Archive, etc.)
    Docker see below
Are you using Cloudflare, mod_security, or similar? (Yes / No)
    No

Summary of the issue I am facing:
I can’t open or edit any document using nextcloud office. The error message is:
Document loading failed Failed to load Nextcloud Office - please try again later

I have followed this post here, and added WOPI 0.0.0.0/0 → did not work
So I looked up Admin settings → logging. I found:
Client error:POST https://monsoon.my-site.org:4443/cool/extract-document-structure?limit=content-control` resulted in a 403 Forbidden response`

So I followed this post here (indeed my collabora is set to a different port) , but no change.
Steps to replicate it

Install NextCloud, using Docker.

The compose file is:
version: '3.9'

services:
  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud:latest
    container_name: nextcloud
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /var/docker/nextcloud/data:/var/www/html
      - /var/docker/nextcloud/config:/var/www/html/config
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: nextcloud
      MYSQL_USER: nextcloud
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: other secret pass
    volumes:
      - /var/docker/nextcloud/db:/var/lib/mysql


Configure Nginx reverse proxy:

The sites-enabled file is:
 server {
    listen 5021 ssl;
    server_name monsoon.my-site.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/monsoon.my-site.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/monsoon.my-site.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name monsoon.my-site.org;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

I can see the nextcloud install now.

Set up collabora using docker:

The compose file is:
version: '3.7'

services:
  collabora:
    image: collabora/code
    container_name: collabora
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5022:9980"
    environment:
      - domain=monsoon.my-site.org
      - "extra_params=--o:ssl.enable=false --o:ssl.termination=true"
    volumes:
      - /opt/collabora/data:/var/www/collabora/data
      - /opt/collabora/loolwsd.xml:/etc/loolwsd/loolwsd.xml


Configure nginx again:

The config is:
server {
listen 4443 ssl;
server_name monsoon.my-site.org;

# Self-signed SSL certificates
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/monsoon.my-site.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/monsoon.my-site.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot


ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

# Proxy requests to the Collabora Docker container
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5022;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header Forwarded "for=$remote_addr;proto=$scheme";
    #proxy_buffering off;
}

client_max_body_size 0;
fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

# Disable buffering to prevent latency
#proxy_request_buffering off;

}


Set instance of collabora to admin settings > office, with port # 4443. Then Restart everything

Go back to the tab where nextcloud is open,. and then under apps > files > click on any odx document. (or even docx) - and the error is popping up.


Log entries
Nextcloud
Using the Copy raw option from Administration settings->Logging screen , i get:
{"reqId":"lywRjoeZcEGDexLp0usU","level":3,"time":"2024-11-29T10:03:00+00:00","remoteAddr":"79.117.107.52","user":"admin","app":"richdocuments","method":"GET","url":"/ocs/v2.php/apps/files/api/v1/templates","message":"Client error: `POST https://monsoon.my-site.org:4443/cool/extract-document-structure?limit=content-control` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:132.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/132.0","version":"30.0.2.2","data":{"app":"richdocuments"},"id":"674997689c36f"}

I edited the log to hide my url.
Web Browser
Using Network analyzer I get:
Request:
POST /browser/3799c094da/cool.html?WOPISrc=https%3A%2F%2Fmonsoon.my-site.org%3A5021%2Findex.php%2Fapps%2Frichdocuments%2Fwopi%2Ffiles%2F567_occmiu611x0t&title=%2FNew%20document.odt&lang=en&closebutton=1&revisionhistory=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: monsoonmy-site.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:132.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/132.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 4348
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: nc_sameSiteCookielax=true; nc_sameSiteCookiestrict=true; __Host-nc_sameSiteCookielax=true; __Host-nc_sameSiteCookiestrict=true; occmiu611x0t=ecebbb737a6c5aa294173b9188848427; oc_sessionPassphrase=wWDd6l8H%2Fa2tMvjGeIVIwtpg7RcQnqMSRX395vo43mnmJqurY4d8%2FCvU5GV09zzugvFoM1AtaoWOOxKnUMMJfUvEsOY1Q%2FhQXWU19GcL4AiuF6RzHF9Wqa8UasvuX%2F6j; nc_username=admin; nc_token=YPyXL7hLyYC2X8ULniIBsuK17vh0h8Yl; nc_session_id=ecebbb737a6c5aa294173b9188848427
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Priority: u=4

Response:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2024 10:31:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip

Web server / Reverse Proxy
The output of my nginx in /var/log is:
[ N 2024-11-29 10:16:58.9382 153218/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1370 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2024-11-29 10:16:58.9667 153222/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1341 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2024-11-29 10:16:58.9683 153222/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:257 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2024-11-29 10:16:58.9861 153222/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1016 ]: Passenger core online, PID 153222
[ N 2024-11-29 10:17:01.1207 153222/T6 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)

(redmine is running on another port)
Configuration
Nextcloud
my config.php file from /path/to/nextcloud is :
$CONFIG = array (
  'htaccess.RewriteBase' => '/',
  'memcache.local' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\APCu',
  'apps_paths' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/apps',
      'url' => '/apps',
      'writable' => false,
    ),

  1 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/custom_apps',
      'url' => '/custom_apps',
      'writable' => true,
    ),
  ),
  'upgrade.disable-web' => true,
  'instanceid' => 'will hide',
  'passwordsalt' => 'will hide',
  'secret' => 'will hide',
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => 'monsoon.my-site.org',
    1 => 'monsoon.my-site.org:5021',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/data',
  'dbtype' => 'sqlite3',
  'version' => '30.0.2.2',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://monsoon.my-site.org:5021',
  'overwritehost' => 'monsoon.my-site.org:5021',
  'overwriteprotocol' => 'https',
  'installed' => true,
  'app_install_overwrite' => 
  array (
    0 => 'files_mindmap',
    1 => 'inventory',
    2 => 'files_3d',
  ),
);

Please help
Thank you.
